# Do Raman spectra of crystals depend on stress, strain or both?

Tags: stress-strain, phonons, raman-spectroscopy

Very fundamental question. I always assumed that the spectra changes, because one changes the inter-atomic distances (strain) only. However, I am not sure this is the entire story.

Does Raman spectra of crystals change with stress too? Can you separate the effects of stress and strain (even theoretically) or are they always intertwined?

Comment: Stress causes strain, and vice versa...

Comment: I understand this, but my line of thought is as follows:
Raman measures the energy of phonons, the vibration properties of the crystal. Strain, changes the inter-atomic distances and decides where the equilibrium is  on the inter-atomic potential curve, which the 2nd derivative of decides stiffness. However, I think stress is a little different. Applied stress causes the extension, but also provides tension. There, tension (like in a instrument) changes the vibrational properties also. Perhaps they are the same. But in papers I see Raman vs. Strain a lot more than stress.

Comment: In a single crystal the two are linked directly through the elasticity tensor. Strain is easier to measure directly, for example using x-ray diffraction (and then comparing that with Raman to calibrate the Raman). So, one usually plots vs strain.

Comment: I can't see how stress itself would have any effect at all.  Stress by itself does not describe a change in the crystal.  The change in the crystal is described by the strain,which of course can be due to the stress.   The properties of the crystal are described by strain, only *indirectly* by stress.

Comment: Jon: It might very well be an ill formed idea/question. I understand that stress and strain are related. I guess the question then changes to - can you have stress in a system with no strain? Or another way, in a non-typical system where stress and strain (even perturbatively) are related in non-linear relationship.

Comment: garyp: My analogy above explains this. For say low q phonons (larger collections of oscillations), stress could change their spectra (perhaps increase energy due to effectively being stiffer) just like tension in a guitar string. However, Raman peaks vs. strain in crystals typically decrease due to anharmonic bond potentials (soften due to decreasing stiffness - 2nd derivative of potential). In this way, I was wondering if there is some competition between these two mechanisms happening. Again, my analogy and understanding very well may be wrong.